# JSON new data push. How to save changes? With AngularJs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, factory

all. I'm new with Angular. I need to find out how to save my JSON changes after *push*.

```
app.controller('ReviewController', function(){
    this.r = {};
    this.addReview = function(product){
        this.r.createdOn = Date.now();
        product.reviews.push(this.r);
        this.r = {};
    };
});
```

also I have this thing, where I get JSON data. I don't know if it would be useful for you to know that

```
app.factory('events', function($http) {
  return function(){
    return $http.get('products.json');
  };
});
app.controller("StoreController", function(events){
        var store = this;
        store.products = [];
        events().success(function(data) {
            store.products = data;
        });
```

One more thing. My products.json file:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Rubinas",
        "price": 199.99,
        "description": "Labai kietas, davai pirkit.",
        "images": {
            "full": "images/gem2.gif",
            "thumb": "images/gem2t.gif"
        },
        "reviews": [
            {
                "stars": 1,
                "body": "Bullshit",
                "author": "Hater",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            },
            {
                "stars": 3,
                "body": "Simple stone!",
                "author": "Dude",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            },
            {
                "stars": 5,
                "body": "Amazing.",
                "author": "Kate",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            }
        ],
        "canPurchase": true,
        "soldOut": false
    },
    {
        "title": "Smaragdas",
        "price": 499.99,
        "description": "Oho, koks.",
        "images": {
            "full": "images/gem3.gif",
            "thumb": "images/gem3t.gif"
        },
        "reviews": [
            {
                "stars": 5,
                "body": "This is so amazing",
                "author": "Steeler",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            },
            {
                "stars": 4,
                "body": "Pretty cool!",
                "author": "Jim",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            },
            {
                "stars": 2,
                "body": "I don't like it very much.",
                "author": "Kim",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            }
        ],
        "canPurchase": true,
        "soldOut": false
    },
    {
        "title": "Deimantas",
        "price": 9999.99,
        "description": "Labai kietas, na bet rimtai.",
        "images": {
            "full": "images/gem4.gif",
            "thumb": "images/gem4t.gif"
        },
        "reviews": [
            {
                "stars": 1,
                "body": "Eww...",
                "author": "Hater",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            },
            {
                "stars": 4,
                "body": "Nice!",
                "author": "Dude",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            },
            {
                "stars": 5,
                "body": "So unbelievible.",
                "author": "Matt",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            },
            {
                "stars": 2,
                "body": "I don't like it.",
                "author": "Steven",
                "createdOn": 1397490980837
            }
        ],
        "canPurchase": true,
        "soldOut": false
    }
]
```

Comment: The client can not mutate/delete files on the server, the data should be send back and then handled by a backend with persistence of somekind

Comment: You can also persist it on localStorage or sessionStorage of your browser.

Comment: That's what I get now - localStorage saving. But how can I do changes in server?

Answer (score 1):

The are some ways to do this

**First :** You can create a **button** say called "save changes", and tell the user after finishing the process of adding new data with your so-called function **addReview**, Hit the **save changes** , and in the on-click of this button , you can create a $http.post request and send your new pushed array into your database (or your json file , whatever it is)

**Second :** You can do the same $http.post in your own function , **addReview**, without creating a button and listening for user to click on **save changes** button.

For example:
 if you want to go for my second solution :

```
       this.addReview = function(product){
         this.r.createdOn = Date.now();
          product.reviews.push(product);
          this.r = {};
          $http.post('yourServerFile',WhateverYouWantToSave)
          .success(function(){
             alert('Your Changes have been saved to database');
          })
        };
        //Dont forget to inject $http into your controller
```

And its better to define a factory/servise for this kind of theories(pushing/adding/sending/deleting somethig from somewhere)

Comment: Almost here. I get alert, but can't see any changes in JSON. Any ideas why?

Comment: `app.controller('ReviewController',['$http', function($http){
        this.r = {};
        this.addReview = function(product){
            this.r.createdOn = Date.now();
            product.reviews.push(this.r);
            var store = this;
            $http.post('/products.json',store.r)
            .success(function(){
               alert('Your Changes have been saved to database');
            });
            this.r = {};
        };
    }]);`
Am I doing this right?

Comment: I think you are pushin an empty array into your abject

Comment: you've defined this.r as an empty object
then in you addReview function, you are pushing this empty object 
why???????

Comment: based on your code
I think you must push your product into your product.reviews, you are pushing this.r which is empty:(

Comment: And also
I dont like your code, why are you confusing yourself by using *this*?
Why dont you just explicitely use $scope?

Comment: You see, I am learning angular from specific resources, that's why I'm using this. And I'm not already familiar with scope. It is not a empty array. It is, but only in begining, than I call function addReview and pass some data from my html form to the app.js

Comment: I see what is wrong. I want to update "reviews" of only 1 product in product.json, but I'm not doing that. I just don't know how should I do that.